# One form to update multiple pages in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, models

Fairly new to `Rails`.  I'm trying to create a form that updates two models, and outputs to two separate show pages.  One, is this possible, and two, how?  I saw a lot of posts about one form being able to update multiple models, but not sure if I can have one form that creates two separate pages.

edit:

Thanks for the comments so far.  And, sorry for the lack of clarity.  basically I have two models. One is for a "Course preview" page.  And the second is for the "Actual Course".  Any user can view the Preview page, but will have to purchase the course to be allowed to view the course page.

What I am trying to do is use 1 form to create the "course preview" and the "course" at the same time.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do you mean having one form create a show page for each model record created?

Comment: please give details about your models and associations. Also some more specification, what do you exactly want to do..

Comment: Two show pages, as in depending on which form you fill in, it gives you the respective show page? Or after you fill in a form, it somehow launches an extra page in a new tab?

Comment: Thanks for the info......sorry for the lack of clarity.  basically i have a form page, and two models.  one model is for a class preview, and one model is for the full class.  a user will be able to view the preview page and if they purchase the class, they will be directed to the full class page.  I was wanting to create a form page in which I can set up both the preview page and the class page at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't render two pages at once, a user can only see one page at a time.

But you can create one page that displays the results with some clever coding.  If you have two models, say Model1 and Model2, and a view for each one, say model1/show.html.erb, you can change the show.html.erb code from:

```
<%= @model.name %>
etc...
```

to

```
<%= render 'display' %>
```

Create a file named _display.html.erb, and put the contents from show.html.erb in there.  Now, when you visit the show page for Model1, it will call the display partial and render all the information accordingly.  Lather, rinse, repeat for Model2.

So, your return page for your dual form would also utilize this very same partial.  The results page for your form would look like:

```
<%= render 'model1/display' %>

<%= render 'model2/display' %>
```

This pulls the partials for each model type and puts it in the results page.

For more information on using partials, see:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials